# Gitlab-ci-token user unable to clone repositories

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to setup a docker runner and successfully registered the runner with gitlab-ce. However, when the job runs it always fails with the follow:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.2 (d171b73)
Using Docker executor with image python:3.4 ...
Starting service postgres:latest ...
Pulling docker image postgres:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image python:3.4 ...
Running on runner-b35ff618-project-96-concurrent-0 via toucan...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/amrstratus/webportal'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.xxxxxxxxx/amrstratus/webportal.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.xxxxxx port 443: Connection refused
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

I tried simply to clone the repository and got a similar error:

```
root@toucan:/tmp# git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:b35ff618453c702944c736668e1c2c@gitlab.xxxxxxxx/amrstratus/webportal.git/
Cloning into 'webportal'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.xxxxxxxx/amrstratus/webportal.git/'
```

Access via https seems to work fine and everything else seems to work.

Any ideas? I am totally stuck.

System Details:

```
Debian 8 (Jessie)
GitLab 8.16.2
GitLab Shell 4.1.1
GitLab Workhorse v1.3.0
GitLab API v3
Git 2.10.2
Ruby 2.3.3p222
Rails 4.2.7.1
PostgreSQL 9.6.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there might be two issue.

Regarding the token itself (and `fatal: Authentication failed` ), see [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22723)

> The CI token is now securely generated for each build. It's available in `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN`.
>   If you're cloning a different repository from `.gitlab-ci.yml` (like we were) your best bet is to use SSH.
>
> Another solution is to use your personal private token:

```
git clone https://<username>:<private-token>@gitlab.anydomainhere.com/developers/<projectname>.git
```

> (please realize this token gives access to all your projects)

The other issue is related to Docker: `fatal: unable to access`

You need to be sure you can communicate to your Gitlab instance ([as in here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1036) or in [issue 305](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/305)).
And [check the ownership as in this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1721).

Comment: Thanks, your post helped me figure out the problem. It was not an authentication issue but an issue related to docker an my firewall blocking the request. Using 
     docker run python:3.4 /usr/bin/curl https://gitlab.xxxx
helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, however, what fixed this issue for me was the adjustments to workhorse as per [this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22723#note_17412129).

Modified `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as follows:

Uncomment this line

```
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
```

Add these 2 lines

```
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
```

Then modified the webserver config to point the reverse proxy to this instead of unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Although a solution is already been given for the problem but using the personal token.
As pointed out, it might be failing because if you cloned using the CI_BUILD_TOKEN/CI_JOB_TOKEN, that is only valid for that job run.
So, if you want the pull to work through the runner everytime, you can specify url while pulling :

```
git pull https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@gitlab.anydomainhere.com/developers/<projectname>.git
```

This way, on every pull request, the new token is used.